# Ethereum Accounts

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, accounts, account-generation

I’m a starter and want to understand how are our wallets(public & private keys) are linked to an account on the mainnet. For example: if I generate a random private key and also get the public key derived from it, but haven’t transacted yet. So, how I can get EVM to have my account which is manageable by my new wallet and EVM will store the account state?

Comment: A few things: 1: your private key IS your account.2: A "wallet" is just an abstraction of using private key to sign transactions. 3: The EVM doesn't know that you've generated a random private key until you make a transaction (how would it know in. the first place?)

Comment: The account is more of a public key than a private key.